# Looking for this book

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have been searching for a Fantasy book that I lost back in 1989 for the last 15 years. I have all but given-up that I will ever find it. Of course I don't remember the name of the book nor the author. My only hope is that someone can help be reading my brief analogy of the book listed below and send me a name. I would appreciate any assistance in this matter.

The book is a fantasy about a mage/warrior living a holy place who has just completed his testing. He has distant hereditary lines to a foreign nation of great wealth and an even greater history of violence, magic, and lewd civil behavior. He is sent there by his masters to "watch" the society.

The arch villain is a great mage who eats manflesh and believes that it strengthens him unto himself. The society uses slaves for all manner of things to include being fed upon by blood eating plants that produce foodstuffs for the society.

One particular scene that might remind someone who reads this of the books name is as follows.... A minion of the arch villain is coaxed into a bottle of purple worms, who while eating him will allow the minion great pleasure, however, the arch villain has tricked the minion and upon entering the bottle and being consumed, he is subjected to great amounts of pain and suffering.

The end of the book culminates with our monk like hero turning to evil and battling the arch villain. He wins by reciting a spell he learns from a demon that causes the arch villain to explode from his "overeating" of manflesh.

I know these paragraphs are probably vague and unhelpful. I remain ever hopeful that "someday" I will find this book and again have it in my fantasy collection. Not to mention, I am dying to read it again.

Comment: You didn't say, was it in English? Do you remember anything about the picture on the cover - if it had one?

Comment: Hi Craig. Rather than posting an expanded version of the previous question please edit the original to add the extra details, or I'm sure one of our regulars would be happy to edit the original question if you're uncertain how to do it.

Comment: I've edited your extra details into the original question, and I've placed a bounty on it to encourage people to answer.